# Should we disable dmesg for non-administrative users?

Tags: linux, permissions, restrictions, dmesg

As I can find in Mac OS X

```
smarek:~ marekseberaold$ dmesg
Unable to obtain kernel buffer: Operation not permitted
usage: sudo dmesg
```

Is this really important, to disable access to dmesg output for non-root / non-administrative users? Why is Apple doing this at all?

Comment: Apparently, the need to run as root comes from the [original BSD command](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/dmesg.8.html). I think that modern FreeBSD has abandoned the need for root `dmesg`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A clear "yes" from my side:

An attacker can use it to snoop kernel messages, e.g. about segfaults, kernel errors and thus use it as feedback loop for exploit optimization. Another usecase: the iptables LOG target will write to same buffer, information about connections of other users can then be misused to spoof packets with better chance for success.

I guess someone skilled will find even more ways to use dmesg to aid in privilege escalation.

Comment: A recent example on Linux: https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2018/09/a-cache-invalidation-bug-in-linux.html
`kernel.dmesg_restrict` is the kernel flag. Similarly, `hidepids` on `/proc` can help. One needs to be careful to not inconvenience users too much, though -- especially if they already have access to `/var/log/kern.log` and the like (e.g., `adm` group)